# Jquery is("li:last-child") not working right

Tags: jquery, selector

The last "div" brokes the selector even if has "li" on the selector. whats wrong? I want to get the "d" in the case

http://jsfiddle.net/46u8G/2/

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <div></div>
</ul>

$("li").click(function(){
    alert($(this).is("li:last-child"));
})
```

Comment: `div` is an invalid child of `ul` in the example markup.

Comment: yea, but imagine some other case with divs and spans. http://jsfiddle.net/46u8G/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick out the last element up front, then do a comparison:

```
var last = $('li:last');
$("li").click(function(){
    var isLast = this == last[0];
    alert(isLast);
});
```

But you'll have to use valid markup for this to work (e.g. no `<div>` children of `<ul>`).

Answer (score 2):

The last child of your `ul` is the `div`, not the `li` with content `d`.

Remove the div and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

This is for your other example:

```
  $("#init").children().each(function(){$(this).click(function(){
  alert($(this).is(":last-child"));
  })
  })
```

If you only want it to work for one element on click, other answer will work.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's looking for the last child, not the last item in the selector. jQuery does support the `:last` pseudo-element though.

```
$("li").click(function(){
    alert($(this).is("li:last"));
})
```

As an aside, a `ul` can't contain a `div`. `ul`s are for lists and should only contain `li`s (or other `ul`s for sub-lists), but this won't affect the jQuery selection... it's just invalid HTML markup.

Comment: this one alerts true for all clicks